# How to configure Elasticsearch sink with appsettings.json?

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog-sinks-elasticsearch

I am configuring Serilog for my application. The intent is to configure Serilog completely through appsettings.json. My problem is, everywhere on the web, Elasticsearch's configuration is explained with C# code.

Meanwhile, I have this in appsettings.json:

```
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Elasticsearch",
        "Args": {
          "Uri": "http://localhost:5601"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ]
```

However, the Elasticsearch sink doesn't pick up this configuration, and 1st chance exceptions show that it is trying to connect to the default port 9200.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the key was to use "nodeUris" instead of "Uri".